# VS Code issues on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, autosave

This problem is very weird to describe...

Sometimes null characters are added to the end of the open document.
Other times lines are deleted from the end of the document.

I feel like these must be related in a way.

I cannot reliably reproduce the error. But it seems to be connected to when I save the document since it happens much more frequently when autosave is enabled.

Installed extensions are:
Python,
Jupyter,
GithubCopilot,
R

The problem appears as soon as the jupyter extension is enabled.

The funny thing is I have the exact same setup on my desktop with absolutely no problems.

I tried removing visual studio code and the files created in the following folders:

%APPDATA%\Code and %USERPROFILE%.vscode - along with the other extension files like .jupyter.

Reinstalled everything.

Same problem.

Comment: Antother thing I have noticed, which might be of relevance: When I'm using jupyter notebooks vs code will exit "focus" of a cell at random time intervals, which is also super annoying

Comment: Update.
As mentioned I have no problems on my desktop.
Out of pure desperacy, I have tried copying and moving all files from my desktop to my laptop.

Still the same problem...
I am seriously at a loss here. There is obviously some minor detail that I´m overlooking, but what and where is it?

Answer (score 0):

You may install the `Prettier` extension. `Prettier` would suggest you add a blank line at the end of files so it may prevent cutting the final line in your saved files. I usually use this method.

You can find it on VS Code Marketplace or the documentation.

Comment: I'm very desperate so I'll try this and return with updates. :)

Comment: I cannot find the specific Beautify extension for python. I can only find one for js.